# How would I import a function template using PInvoke?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, templates, pinvoke

In my C# code, I need to call a function from a C++ Dll that I wrote.The function is generic.
So , should I just import it like this:

```
[DllImport("myDll.dll")]
private static extern TypeName functionName<TypeName>( int arg1, int arg2 );
```

Is this correct syntax?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot work, there is no main-stream C++ compiler that makes templates exportable.  Furthermore, templates are instantiated by the C++ compiler through type erasure, similar to the way Java generics works.  In other words, the concrete callable functions have to be embedded in the DLL by the C++ compiler.  They are no longer generic.

As an alternative, you can write a ref class in the C++/CLI language.  That produces a true .NET generic class, usable by any .NET language that supports generics.